# SciKit Learn - Mathematical model behind linear regression?

Tags: python, math, scikit-learn, linear-regression

What mathematical model does the [Linear Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression) function use in scikit learn? The Ordinary Least Squares model has more than one way to minimize the cost function. I've found the form of the function it solves [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html), but I'm also interested which method it uses exactly. Can anyone elaborate? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically hunt around the source code enough, and you'll find it.

- In [`base.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L349), you can find it uses `linal.lstsq`.
- In [`linalg.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/linalg.py), you can see that `lstsq` uses the [`dglelsd` family](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/dgelsd.htm).
- This family is SVD-related. It [uses SVD to solve the original problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974193/why-does-svd-provide-the-least-squares-solution-to-ax-b).